# What stops website owner from hiding CPM/CPV ads?

Tags: ads, banner

I just started a website and want to put some ads on it to make it pay for itself. Given that nobody ever clicks on those, I thought that CPC (cost-per-click) is not an option and decided to go with CPM/CPV ads. Here's my question. What exactly stops me from putting hundred of those on each page of my web site and wrapping them into something like

```
<div style="visibility:hidden">ad banner</div>
```

The impressions/views would still be counted, right? Or am I not understanding something.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not that easy.
The ad provider measures how often the ad is being viewed, not how often it is added to an webpage. If it is hidden, it is not rendered and therefore not being counted.

Maybe you would like to read about [Web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon):

Comment: but how? how do they check if it was visible. I believe that was the original question.

Comment: I didn't mean the same ad placed hundred times, I meant hundred different ads placed on each page. And okay, what if it's not hidden, but resized to very small div? e.g. <div style="width: 1px; height: 1px"> ad </div>

Comment: Maybe it is technically possible, but this is certainly forbidden by ad providers.
If something is hidden, the web beacon (pixel) is not being delivered and wouldn't be counted.